# Take screenshots of specific application window on Mac

Tags: macos, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to make a screen cast application which casts individual application windows instead of the whole screen. To start with I'm trying to take simple screenshots of individual applications on my mac using Xcode.

So far, I'm trying to make use of `CGWindowListCreateImage` but I'm running into problems.

**EDIT**
So here's a small example of how I managed to get the WindowID. It's pretty simple afterwards to take a screenshot using it.
First you add a global monitor for events, more specifically NSMouseEvents. I used mouse down. The window information is stored in the mouse event.

```
    CGWindowID windowID = (CGWindowID)[event windowNumber];
```

You can then take a screenshot of JUST the app, without shadows etc using the code below.

```
CGImageRef image = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectNull, kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow, self.WindowID, kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming);
```

Let me know if you need more.

Comment: What are the problems that you run into?

Comment: actually i fixed it! I'll post the code below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So here's a small example of how I managed to get the WindowID. It's pretty simple afterwards to take a screenshot using it. First you add a global monitor for events, more specifically NSMouseEvents. I used mouse down. The window information is stored in the mouse event.

```
CGWindowID windowID = (CGWindowID)[event windowNumber];
```

You can then take a screenshot of JUST the app, without shadows etc using the code below.

```
CGImageRef image = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectNull, kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow, self.WindowID, kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming);
```

Let me know if you need more.

Comment: So, what if there is no event? e.g. In my app, I just need the windowID of another app and take its screenshot, without have to do a mouse click first?

Comment: No, the mouse click is no the only way. You can get a list of currently active windows and their window ID's and use this to take a screenshot.You can do this using the GWindowListCopyWindowInfo API

Comment: How about simply using -[NSWindow windowNumber]?

Comment: if you have multiple windows, they'll have unique window numbers, so to get a screenshot of the window you want, you must know its window number. which is why you need some kind of event to identify it, like a mouse click.

Comment: if i want to take a safari browser screenshot , how can i determines?

Answer (score 3):

Based on user3339357 's answer, in Swift 3

```
let gImage = CGWindowListCreateImage(
      CGRect.null,
      CGWindowListOption.optionIncludingWindow,
      CGWindowID(window.windowNumber),
      CGWindowImageOption.bestResolution)

let image = NSImage(cgImage: cgImage!, size: window.frame.size)
```